# why does 0x80000000 & 0x80000000 low then 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, 64-bit

why does in nodejs

```
0x80000000 & 0x80000000 < 0
```

but

```
0x40000000 & 0x40000000 > 0
```

---

and if i use more big hex like `0x800000000`

does it will has any hidden bug ?

[POSTAG.ts](https://github.com/bluelovers/node-segment/blob/master/lib/POSTAG.ts)

---

console.log(0x80000000) // => 2147483648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way numbers are presented in computer ([two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

The hex digit `8` is binary `1000`, so the binary representation of the number in the register has the leftmost bit `1` (negative). Hex digit `4` is `0100`, so it starts with `0` (positive).

```
> 0x80000000
-2147483648
> 0x40000000
1073741824
```

It has nothing to do with the `&` operator, especially since ANDing two the same thing gives that thing again.

Answer (score 0):

The leftmost digit is 8 in the first case and the 4 in the second case.Anything from 0-7 is positive and 8-f is negative. Because 8 in hex is 1000 and 4 in hex is 0100.